# Javascript replace content of html

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am trying to replace some content of html page. I successfully pick it to string, but when I try to put it back, html shows me "Undefined"

```
var count = 1;
var count2 = 0;
document.getElementById("element1").onkeyup = function () {
    if (count2 === 0) {
        var content1 = document.getElementById("element2").innerHTML;
        count2 = 1;
    }
    if (document.getElementById("element1").value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("element2").innerHTML = "";
        count = 0;
    } else if (count === 0) {
        document.getElementById("element2").innerHTML = content1;
        count = 1;
    }
};
```

Anybody knows why?

Comment: Well `content1` is undefined if `count2 != 0`

Comment: Declare var content1 as a global variable

Comment: What'are you trying to do? Is unclear what's `content1` in the last `if block`

Answer (score 0):

it's a hoisting issue, declare content1 at the start of the function, not inside an if statemenent

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have got it solved. I had to make content1 global variable.

```
var count = 1;
var content1;
window.onload = function () {
    content1 = document.getElementById("element1").innerHTML;
};
document.getElementById("element2").onkeyup = function () {

    if (document.getElementById("element2").value !== "") {
        document.getElementById("element1").innerHTML = "";
        count = 0;
    } else if (count === 0) {
        document.getElementById("element1").innerHTML = content1;
        count = 1;
    }
};
```